# Finding the minimum distance (shortest path) passing through at least $k$ distinct points in plane.

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, discrete-optimization

Consider $n$ distinct points $(x_1,y_1), \dots ,(x_n,y_n)$. From these points, let the starting point be $(x_s,y_s)$, and let the final point be $(x_f,y_f)$. We need to find the minimum distance from $(x_s,y_s)$ to $(x_f,y_f)$ passing through at least $k$ points other than  $(x_s,y_s)$ and $(x_f,y_f)$ with $(0 \le k \le n-2)$.

Note: starting point and final point need not necessarily be distinct.

My attempt was not efficient at all: I listed all possible paths one by one and calculate the distnace using the formula $d=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$ and the sum all of these distances. However, more points will be much more waste of time.

---

Consider these as examples:

- A person likes to visit the cities $A, B, C, D, E, F, G,$ and $H$. Currently he is in $A$, and he wants $H$ to be his final destination, but he wants to visit at least two cities (other than $A$ and $H$).
- A person likes to visit the cities $A, B, C, D, E, F, G,$ and $H$. Currently he is in $A$, and he wants $A$ to be his final destination, but he wants to visit at least three cities (other than $A$).

---

Your help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this literally the Travelling Salesman Problem (with Euclidean distance)? The "returning to starting point" aspect doesn't affect the time complexity of the problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: @AdamRubinson Thanks for mentioning that. But I believe it is not exactly the same. The problem I posted, we have $n$ (total number of points) and $k$ (minimum number of points to be visited). Secondly, in the Travelling_salesman_problem, both the point of departure and the point of arrival are the same, but in my problem, the need not necessarily be same. Did I misunderstand the Travelling_salesman_problem?

Comment: It might not be the exact same as the classical version of the TSP, but there are many *variations* of it, and I would consider this to be a variation of it, that has likely been studied before. In any case, I would include "graph theory" as a tag.

Answer (score 1):

Closely related problems where you need not visit all points are *optimal subtour problem*, *orienteering problem*, are *prize-collecting TSP*.  Like with the TSP, you can solve the problem via a branch-and-cut algorithm where you dynamically introduce (generalized) subtour elimination constraints when they are violated, as in the Dantzig-Fulkerson-Johnson formulation.  For small enough $n$, you can get by with a variant of the weaker but compact Miller-Tucker-Zemlin formulation.

Let $s$ and $t$ be the source and sink nodes, respectively.  Let binary decision variable $x_{ij}$ indicate whether directed arc $(i,j)$ is traversed.  In both formulations, the traditional assignment constraints from TSP are
\begin{align}
\sum_j x_{ij} &= 1 &&\text{for all $i$}\\
\sum_i x_{ij} &= 1 &&\text{for all $j$}
\end{align}
and should be replaced with
\begin{align}
\sum_j x_{ij} &= 1 &&\text{for $i=s$}\\
\sum_i x_{ij} &= 1 &&\text{for $j=t$}\\
\sum_j x_{ij} &\le 1 &&\text{for $i\not= s$}\\
\sum_i x_{ij} &\le 1 &&\text{for $j\not= t$}\\
\sum_{i,j} x_{ij} &\ge k &&
\end{align}